# How to extend a table cell across multiple columns when rendered in R Shiny?

Tags: r, html-table, shiny

I have a dataframe of values that I'm attempting to render as a table in R Shiny. There are certain values which I want to extend to take up multiple columns in the same way in which you'd use the HTML  rowspan attribute. However, if I were to do that I'd have to create the whole table from scratch, and I would much prefer to use the DT library for easy conversion from my datatable.

As an example I've created the following script:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

# server.R

library(DT)

function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- data.frame(A = c("Trial 1", 1, 1, 1), B = c("", 1, 1, 1), C = c("", 1, 1, 1),
                     D = c("Trial 2", 2, 2, 2), E = c("", 2, 2, 2), F = c("", 2, 2, 2),
                     G = c("Trial 3", 3, 3, 3), H = c("", 3, 3, 3), I = c("", 3, 3, 3))

    DT::datatable(df,
                  options = list(dom = "t",
                                 ordering = FALSE))
  })

}
```

This script renders the following UI:

[image: UI output of above R Shiny app]

How can I expand out the cells containing "Trial 1", "Trial 2", and Trial 3" so that they each take up three columns?

Comment: Would it be suitable to add the first row as a grouped header above the ordinary column names?

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to target any cell, not just header cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a custom container to add the column group names as real column headers:

```
# ui.R

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

# server.R

library(DT)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 1), B = c(1, 1, 1), C = c(1, 1, 1),
                 D = c(2, 2, 2), E = c(2, 2, 2), F = c(2, 2, 2),
                 G = c(3, 3, 3), H = c(3, 3, 3), I = c(3, 3, 3))

myContainer <- htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(),
      th(colspan = 3, 'Trial 1', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 3, 'Trial 2', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 3, 'Trial 3', class = "dt-center")
    ),
    tr(
      th(),
      lapply(names(df), th)
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df, container = myContainer,
                  options = list(dom = "t", ordering = FALSE,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"))
                  ))
  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Alternativly, if you really want that first row to have colspans we can use the `initComplete` option to call a JavaScript function when the table is rendered. Here is the server part only:

```
jsc <- '
function(settings, json) {
  $("td:contains(\'Trial\')").attr("colspan", "3").css("text-align", "center");
  $("tbody > tr:first-child > td:empty").remove();
}'

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- data.frame(A = c("Trial 1", 1, 1, 1), B = c("", 1, 1, 1), C = c("", 1, 1, 1),
                     D = c("Trial 2", 2, 2, 2), E = c("", 2, 2, 2), F = c("", 2, 2, 2),
                     G = c("Trial 3", 3, 3, 3), H = c("", 3, 3, 3), I = c("", 3, 3, 3))
    DT::datatable(df, options = list(dom = "t", ordering = FALSE, initComplete = JS(jsc)))
  })

}
```

In the first row of the JS function we select all cells that contain the word *Trial* and add the corresponding attributes and styles. Afterwards we select all empty cells, that are a direct descendant of a row element which in turn is the first child of the body of the table and remove them from the DOM. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) you find a general reference on CSS selectors like `>`.

**Output:**

[image]