# Multiple header in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, names, multirow

I have a function that return the following dataframe

[image]

(code for toy example below)

```r
df <- data.frame(
      var = c("var1 ------", "mod1", "mod2", "var2 ------","mod1", "mod2", "mod3"),
      X1_Y1 = c(NA,0,1,NA,1,3,5),
      X1_Y2 = c(NA,2,5,NA,2,4,10),
      X2_Y1 = c(NA,8,8,NA,3,3,1),
      X2_Y2 = c(NA,9,3,NA,0,6,2))
```

For context, these are just weighted statistics of one variable of interest (`Y` with values `Y1` and `Y2`) crossed by explanatory variables (`var1` and `var2`) and stratified by another variable (`X` with values `X1` and `X2`).

What I would like is to have a double row header such as :
[image]

My constraint is that it has to be done on specific objects : either directly on R `dataframe` or possibly on `DT::datatable`. But I am not sure this is possible, and if so, really don't know how.

I found solutions using `flextable` or raw html but it does not suit really well my goal. (EDIT : also tried the `kableExtra::add_header_above` which works but prevents me from keeping my `DT::datatable` object in my rmd)

**EDIT :** the folowing solutions *almost* do the job BUT it seems to me that I need to leave aside the `DT::datatable` represensation.

[image]

Comment: You may be confusing the object itself with the *representation* of the object on screen or on paper.  Take a look at `kableExtra::add_header_above`.

Comment: I don't think I'm confusing but my question is probably unclear. Using `add_header_above` indeed works for that purpose but transform my table to a `knitr::kable` object and I wish I could keep in the end my `DT:datatable` object

Comment: Then what you want may simply not possible.  `data.frame`s have no concept of "spanning headers"  (or even simple headers).  It *is* possible to add spanning headers to the `datatable` *representation* of a `data.frame` (which is a "transformation" of the `data.frame`, so I don't understand your objection to transforming it to a `kable` object).  See section 2.6 of [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) for example.

Comment: "also tried the kableExtra::add_header_above which works but prevents me from keeping my DT::datatable object in my rmd": this is *simply not true*.

Comment: Your expected output appears to be quite unclear. `library(gt); gt(df, rowname_col = "var") |> cols_label(.list = as.list(sub(".*_", "", colnames(df))) |> setNames(colnames(df))) |> tab_spanner(label = unique(sub("_.*", "", colnames(df[-1])))[1], columns = 2:3) |> tab_spanner(label = unique(sub("_.*", "", colnames(df[-1])))[2], columns = 4:5)` Are you looking for an output like this?

Comment: thanks @Limey for your comments and yes you are right sorry, `DT:datatable` is a *representation* of a `data.frame` but includes js for interactivity, `kable` does not. This is why I wanted to keep my `DT:datatable` object in the rmd. I mentioned the solution using raw html, it works but problem is I would have to custom each table produced with my function in the rmd with a specific table container. What I want is probably not possible or at least not easily. I am gonna try to automate the html custom table container with the DT::datatable object as input.

Comment: "also tried the kableExtra::add_header_above which works but prevents me from keeping my DT::datatable object in my rmd": this is simply not true. Ok but then how to use `kableExtra::add_header_above` and keep a `DT::datatable` object in my rmd ?

Comment: @Friede thanks this is very close but again, problem is that I lose the `DT::datatable` representation. I am gonna try with the custom table container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Friede and @Limey answers, plus section 2.6 of [this doc](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), plus [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722100/rmarkdown-creat-column-headers-using-dt) that I missed at first, I came up with this solution, that should work for every df passed as long as column names follow the pattern
`ValueOfStratifyingVariable_ValueOfInterestVariable`

```r
f <- function(df) {
  # get names for both rows of header
  values <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(names(df)[-1], "_")),
                 ncol=2,
                 byrow=TRUE)

  head_row1 <- table(values[,1])
  head_row2 <- values[,2]

  # create custom table container
  sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
    class = 'display',
    thead(
      tr(
        th(rowspan = 2, 'Var'),
        lapply(names(head_row1),
               function(x) {th(colspan = head_row1[[x]],
                               x, class = 'dt-center')})
      ),
      tr(
        lapply(head_row2,  th)
      )
    )
  ))
  
  # apply container to DT::datatable
  DT::datatable(df, container = sketch, rownames = FALSE)
}

f(df)
```

This produces the expected output :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

You might reshape your data a bit and investigate the `container`-argument in `DT::datatable()`, cp. section [2.6 Custom Table Container](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/?_gl=1*1cpuzam*_ga*MTI2ODU0ODg0NC4xNzAxNzc2OTI2*_ga_2C0WZ1JHG0*MTcxMDQxNzA2Ny4yNi4xLjE3MTA0MTcwNzUuMC4wLjA.). Further refinement should get you close to your expected output.

```r
df = data.frame(
  # var name changed from var to mod 
  mod = c("var1 ------", "mod1", "mod2", "var2 ------","mod1", "mod2", "mod3"),
  X1_Y1 = c(NA,0,1,NA,1,3,5),
  X1_Y2 = c(NA,2,5,NA,2,4,10),
  X2_Y1 = c(NA,8,8,NA,3,3,1),
  X2_Y2 = c(NA,9,3,NA,0,6,2))
df = cbind(grp = c(rep("var1", 2), rep("var2", 3)), df[-c(1, 4), ])
spans = c("Grouping", unique(sub("_.*", "", colnames(df)))[3:4])
cnms = sub(".*_", "", colnames(df))

library(DT)
library(htmltools)

sketch = withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      lapply(spans, th, colspan = 2, class = "dt-center")
      ),
    tr(
      lapply(cnms, th)
      )
    )
  )
)
datatable(df, container = sketch, rownames = FALSE)
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: yes indeed, thank you ! i was actually working on it and will post an answer right now

Comment: Is it really needed to keep the `var = c("var1 ------", "mod1", "mod2", "var2 ------","mod1", "mod2", "mod3")` as a single column? I think it has downsides and readability is rather low.

Comment: it is arguable, but it is actually a request from the resarch team i'm working with. and i have to say when the number of explanatory variables (the ones that are in this column) is really high, it helps a bit separating those variables and hence reading